# not getting data in the list of my modal

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

THis is my html code with the modal function

```
<div class="modal fade" id="listSensorModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="listSensorModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="deviceModal">Followers List</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <br>
            <div class="row form-group has-feedback" ng-repeat="sensors in listedSensors">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                {{sensors.id}}
              </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                <!-- <input type="checkbox" ng-model="devices.deviceActive" bootstrap-switch class="make-switch" data-on="success" data-off="warning" ng-change="changeStatus(devices)"> -->
              </div> 
            <!--    <div class="col-md-3">
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="editSensors(sensors)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="removeSensor(sensors.id)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-show="!sensors.deviceId" ng-click="linkToDevice(sensors)"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-show="sensors.deviceId"  ng-click="UnlinkDevice(sensors)"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
            </div> -->
          </div>
          <div class="row form-group has-feedback" ng-show="listedSensors.length==0">
            <h3 align="center">No Sensors here</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="showAddSensorModal()">Add a New Sensor</button> -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my Js code which shows the modal.Am getting data here but not the modal.

```
$scope.launchSensorModal = function(){
 // $rootScope.showLoadingMessage('Please Wait');
API.followers().
then(function(responseData){
  if(typeof responseData === 'object'){
     // $rootScope.hideLoadingMessage('Please Wait');
      $scope.listedSensors = responseData.data[0];
      console.log("Sensor",responseData.data);
      console.log("Sensor",responseData.data[0].full_name);
      $('#listSensorModal').modal('show');
       console.log("Sensor",responseData.data);
      console.log("Sensor",responseData.data[0].full_name);
  }
  else{
    console.log("Failed to get Listed Sensor. Please try again",responseData);
  }
},function(responseData){
    console.log("Failed to get Listed Sensor. Please try again",responseData);
})}
```

my console looks like this:

```
 Sensor [Object]0: Objectfull_name: "Skater Gal"id: "2351640229"profile_picture: "https://igcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xft1/t51.2885-19/11906329_960233084022564_1448528159_a.jpg"username: "_skaterg1rl"__proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array[0]
navbar.js:45 Sensor Skater Gal
navbar.js:47 Sensor [Object]
navbar.js:48 Sensor Skater Gal
```

Am not getting the data to the list in my modal.
can anyone help me??

Comment: can anyone help me??

Comment: what is at line number 45,47 & 48 in navbar.js

Comment: those are line points in js page

Comment: What do you use at the backend my friend.

Comment: front end is angular

Comment: I don't really understand your code to be honest. Despite the fact that I use Angular and Node.

Comment: Hey man I understood your code, you there?

Comment: You are getting nothing as repeated data of object?

Comment: nope....i am not getting the value to my modal

Comment: can anyone help me with this??

Comment: can anyone give me a solution for this